# Does a function cache exist in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, caching, lru

In Python we have [`lru_cache`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html) as a function wrapper. Add it to your function  and the function will only be evaluated once per different input argument.

Example (from Python docs):

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

>>> [fib(n) for n in range(16)]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610]

>>> fib.cache_info()
CacheInfo(hits=28, misses=16, maxsize=None, currsize=16)
```

I wonder whether a similar thing exists in **Matlab**? At the moment I am using cache files, like so:

```
function result = fib(n):
% FIB example like the Python example. Don't implement it like that!
cachefile = ['fib_', n, '.mat'];
try
    load(cachefile);
catch e
    if n < 2
        result = n;
    else
        result = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
    end
    save(cachefile, 'result');
end
end
```

The problem I have with doing it this way, is that if I change my function, I need to delete the cachefile.

Is there a way to do this with Matlab realising when I changed the function and the cache has become invalidated?

Comment: I would use a container.Map stored in a persistent variable.

Comment: If you can write stuff to a cache, it should not be too hard to include the date the file was last edited. Once you notice that this is different, clear it. I suppose this will only be worthwile for quite expensive functions, otherwise just consider storing the output in a grid or so during the session.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin, this looks nice but fails  to recognize changes of the function.

Comment: @Daniel: a container.Map will also not recognize changes of my function. (Let's assume I change fib to be `fib(n) = fib(n-1) + 2*fib(n-2)`)

Comment: @Unapiedra: A persistent variable is cleared if a function is updated.

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks I didn't realise that. I have a version now, where it is stored persistently but of course not across sessions. I think I'll write some stuff to disk and let the persistent variable tell me changes of the file.

Comment: If you're caching to a file, maybe you should use temp files. The [`tempname`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tempname.html) function is useful for this.

Comment: `save(cachefile, 'result');`? I wrote "caching to a file". That's not the same thing as caching files. You can use a temp file for your `cachefile`. The idea is that you don't need to worry about your hard drive filling up with cache files (even if you're careful to delete them in your code, a crash or error can leave the files behind).

Comment: @horchler, you are right. Comment deleted. However, I do want to keep my cache across Matlab sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created something like this for my own personal use: a [CACHE](https://github.com/horchler/SHCTools/blob/0a48108ddec519c39b9e14c9aea6973893ea4228/SHCTools/%40CACHE/CACHE.m) class. (I haven't documented the code yet though.) It appears to be more flexible than Python's `lru_cache` (I wasn't aware of that, thanks) in that it has several methods for adjusting exactly what gets cached (to save memory) and how the comparisons are made. It could still use some refinement (@Daniel's suggestion to use the [`containers.Map`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.mapclass.html) class is a good one – though it would limit compatibility with old Matlab versions). The code is on GitHub so you're welcome to fork and improve it.

Here is a basic example of how it can be used:

```
function Output1 = CacheDemo(Input1,Input2)

persistent DEMO_CACHE

if isempty(DEMO_CACHE)
    % Initialize cache object on first run
    CACHE_SIZE = 10; % Number of input/output patterns to cache
    DEMO_CACHE = CACHE(CACHE_SIZE,Input1,Input2);
    CACHE_IDX = 1;
else
    % Check if input pattern corresponds something stored in cache
    % If not, return next available CACHE_IDX
    CACHE_IDX = DEMO_CACHE.IN([],Input1,Input2);
    if ~isempty(CACHE_IDX) && DEMO_CACHE.OUT(CACHE_IDX) > 0
        [~,Output1] = DEMO_CACHE.OUT(CACHE_IDX);
        return;
    end
end

% Perform computation
Output1 = rand(Input1,Input2);

% Save output to cache CACHE_IDX
DEMO_CACHE.OUT(CACHE_IDX,Output1);
```

I created this class to cache the results from time-consuming stochastic simulations and have since used it to good effect in a few other places. If there is interest, I might be willing to spend some time documenting the code sooner as opposed to later. It would be nice if there was a way to limit memory use as well (a big consideration in my own applications), but getting the size of arbitrary Matlab datatypes is not trivial. I like your idea of caching to a file, which might be a good idea for larger data. Also, it might be nice to create a "lite" version that does what Python's `lru_cache` does.

Comment: This LRU cache might help to limit the memory used and increase lookup speed: https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/68836-least-recently-used-lru-cache

Comment: @Vasco I fixed the broken link to point to point to an earlier instance of the repo.

Answer (score 2):

Since matlab 2017 this is available:
https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memoizedfunction.html

```
a = memoized(@sin)
```